# Empty space between two grid items? Also becomes bigger when page height increases

Tags: sass, media-queries, css-grid

I'm making a portfolio website and have put a media query for when the screen's width becomes 900px to place all my grid items vertically. Everything looked good except the fact that there was a big space between the grid items Project 2 and Project 3.

[Here is how Project 1 and 2 look together, this is what I want.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i89Iu.png)

[This is how it looks between Project 2 and 3.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxUfB.png)

This is my media query btw (SCSS):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px)
.container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 0.1fr 0.1fr 0.4fr 1fr;
    align-items: stretch;
    grid-template-areas:
        "nav"
        "main"
        "project1"
        "project2"
        "project3"
        "project4"
        "project5"
        "project6"
```

I have grid gap set to 0 also.

I tried setting bottom margin and padding of Project2 to 0 because I thought that might be causing the issue, but that didn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't anything to do with my media query. My grid-template-rows just had to be set to 1fr in the media query and it was all fixed.